# transactWrite on DynamoDB is not ACID across multiple tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have two tables in DynamoDB and wants to do PUT and Update operation on both tables. Below are the params:

```json
{
    "TransactItems": [
        {
            "Put": {
                "Item": {
                    "ref": 0,
                    "date": 0
                },
                "TableName": "dev-table"
            }
        },
        {
            "Put": {
                "Item": {
                    "ref": 1,
                    "date": 0
                },
                "TableName": "dev-table"
            }
        },
        {
            "Update": {
                "TableName": "dev-table-metadata",
                "Key": {
                    "metaDataKey": "refConsumed"
                },
                "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                    ":s": 1
                },
                "UpdateExpression": "SET metaDataValue = :s",
                "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So here two `Put` operations are happening on `dev-table` and one `Update` operation is on `dev-table-metadata`

I am triggering `transactWrite` in a loop for 10 times and the response is returned okay, but for few iteration I get below error

`TransactionCanceledException: Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [None, None, TransactionConflict]`

My assumption is that in these cases whole transaction should get cancelled, but first two Put operations are written to table and last update is not.

Comment: Are you always sending the same transaction? In that case it could still be the results of the former requests.

Comment: There is new value to all three operations on each iterations.

I am doing it in node lambda like below
`let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
dynamo.transactWrite(params, function(err, data) {
...
})`

Comment: I managed to find out the reason behind this behaviour. It's because of async nature of `TransactWriteItems` commands. so basically in a for loop from 1 to 10, 10 `TransactWriteItems` commands were triggered and they were completing in a async manner. so when I looked at the db tables at the end, it lead to me think that, these transaction are not ACID. 

according to my use-case I need to run these in sync manner. anyway thanks for your help @Maurice

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this using the script you can see below with two put operations to one table and an update to another in a transaction. **I wasn't able to reproduce this.** **Please include code to make this reproducible.**

Aside from that I tend to trust the AWS documentation and my experience that this is actually ACID compliant.

> `TransactWriteItems` is a synchronous and idempotent write operation that groups up to 25 write actions in a single all-or-nothing operation. These actions can target up to 25 distinct items in one or more DynamoDB tables within the same AWS account and in the same Region. The aggregate size of the items in the transaction cannot exceed 4 MB. **The actions are completed atomically so that either all of them succeed or none of them succeeds.**
>
> — [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-apis-txwriteitems) (emphasis mine)

My attempt to reproduce this:

```py
import typing

import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

TABLE_1 = "tbl1"
TABLE_2 = "tbl2"


def create_table_if_not_exists(table_name: str):

    try:
        boto3.client("dynamodb").create_table(
            AttributeDefinitions=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "AttributeType": "S"}],
            TableName=table_name,
            KeySchema=[{"AttributeName": "PK", "KeyType": "HASH"}],
            BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST"
        )
    except ClientError as err:
        if err.response["Error"]["Code"] == 'ResourceInUseException':
            # Table already exists
            pass
        else:
            raise err

def transact_write(put_1_value, put_2_value, update_1_value):
    client = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    client.transact_write_items(
        TransactItems=[
            {
                "Put": {
                    "Item": {"PK": {"S": put_1_value}},
                    "TableName": TABLE_1
                }
            },
            {
                "Put": {
                    "Item": {"PK": {"S": put_2_value}},
                    "TableName": TABLE_1
                }
            },
            {
                "Update": {
                    "TableName": TABLE_2,
                    "Key": {
                        "PK": {"S": str(update_1_value)}
                    },
                    "UpdateExpression": "SET itemValue = :value",
                    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                        ":value": {"S": "some_value"}
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table_if_not_exists(TABLE_1)
    create_table_if_not_exists(TABLE_2)

    for n in range(100):
        print(f"Write #{n}")
        transact_write("a", "b", 1)
```